# Smart UV Project Distorts Color Map

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm new to Blender and I recently asked on my last post/question that I was having problems with baking textures. I have fixed that problem, however, I have a new problem now. Every time I Smart UV Project the Image Texture seems to distort.

Before I UV Project:
[image]

After (You can see that it is slightly distorted):
[image]

Here is a download to the .blend file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/f7rhz3i5vewqg66/SeweragePothole2.blend/file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Smart UV Project* will cut all the faces that have an angle over the set *Angle*, so it tends to create separate islands, and it will organize the islands the way it wants. It's not the best way to project an image onto the surface in the *UV Editor* (but it's typically the best way to unwrap when you want to texture paint on your 3D view because in that case you don't care a lot about how the islands are organized in the *UV Editor*).

A good solution in your case is to use the *Cube Projection* mode, as it will consider the orientation of your faces, and project the texture on both the front and sides.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you once again 